# How do i code a deposit/withdraw solution like stake.com?

Tags: solidity, binance-smart-chain, withdrawal

I want to build a similar solution, where users can deposit BNB to a smart contract and we will then credit the user with in-game tokens in our game.
When a user wants to withdraw we need a solution where we can call the smart contract with example: payout 1 BNB to wallet 0xbxxxxxxx

Is there any services that provides this today and How does stake.com manage?

Comment: Your question is too broad. There different ways to solve a staking contract, a crowdsale, etc. It shouldn't bee too hard to write once the rules are defined.